# servicemix 4.5 NoInitialContextException

Tags: java, osgi, jndi, apache-servicemix

We have the osgi application that perfectly worked on Servicemix 5. But for some reasons we must migrate to Servicemix 4.5. I tried it and got this

```
Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause:
org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL MapperConfiguration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.datasource.DataSourceException: There was an error configuring JndiDataSourceTransactionPool. Cause: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

What does it need?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Aries JNDI feature?

```
features:install jndi
```

Comment: I thought that it must be installed. So, after install I got the same exception, but without any message `Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException`